# Align two ggplots when one of them has aspect.ratio = 1

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I would like to align a volcano plot and a bar plot vertically (same length of y axis but different scales). However I am unable to align them while keeping the aspect ratio of 1 for the volcano plot. I tried the ggpubr, egg, cowplot and gridExtra packages with no success. Am I missing some parameter? I will appreciate your help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to familiarize yourself with the site. To get the best possible help, it would be handy to edit your post and include a minimum working example of your problem. See for instance [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for about asking questions

Comment: Hi there, have you tried the [patchwork](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/) package? It typically does a nice job of aligning panels.

Comment: OP, can you share some code and a representative example?